# Different queries same execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

I'm updating the syntax of some queries that are running in SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2016. The query in question uses a very old syntax ( *= ). After running the old code and the new one, I have the same result, the same execution plan, but I'm wondering if the "translation" I did is correct.

Can someone explain why different queries have the same execution plan? I have seen the opposite, but this is new for me.

Is the query I wrote equivalent to the old one? Please do not focus on the tables name, but on the correct join of the tables.

Here is what I have:

```
Select 
    Count(*) As Cnt 
From 
    FNFItemFat, FUnidade, FNCM, FSitTributaria, 
    FTipoIPI FK_FNFITEMFAT_FTIPOIPI1, FNotaFiscalFat NOTA1 
Where 
    NOTA1.CodNFInsumos = fNFItemFat.CodNFInsumos 
    and FNFItemFat.CodNCM *= FNCM.CodNCM 
    and FNFItemFat.CodSitTrib = FSitTributaria.CodSitTrib 
    and FNFItemFat.CodUnidade = FUnidade.CodUnidade 
    and FNFItemFat.CodTipoIPI = FK_FNFITEMFAT_FTIPOIPI1.CodTipoIPI
```

Here is what I did:

```
Select 
    Count(*) As Cnt 
From 
    FNFItemFat fNFItemFat
Inner Join 
    FNotaFiscalFat NOTA1 on NOTA1.CodNFInsumos = fNFItemFat.CodNFInsumos
Left Join 
    FNCM fNCM on fNCM.CodNCM = fNFItemFat.CodNCM
Inner Join 
    FSitTributaria fSitTributaria on fSitTributaria.CodSitTrib = fNFItemFat.CodSitTrib
Inner Join 
    FUnidade fUnidade on fUnidade.CodUnidade = fNFItemFat.CodUnidade
Inner Join 
    FTipoIPI FK_FNFITEMFAT_FTIPOIPI1 on FK_FNFITEMFAT_FTIPOIPI1.CodTipoIPI = fNFItemFat.CodTipoIPI
```

Comment: That is a correct translation. The plans are the same, because the query is the same. The different syntaxes are expressing the same semantic meaning. My only comment is I'd be explicit and say "LEFT OUTER JOIN" instead of just "LEFT JOIN" even though the result is the same. I always fully qualify my JOINs.

Comment: For me OUTER is redundant, there is no other kind of LEFT JOIN. :) But not a big deal either way. Kudos for fixing your legacy code. It is not easy to take that antiquated join syntax and update it. There isn't much documentation left about what they mean because they have been out of use for so long now.

Comment: If the execution plans are identical, that proves you have properly converted the syntax and will get identical results. Ideally, SQL Server will always generate the same (optimal) plan for semantically identical queries, although that doesn't always happen in practice.

Comment: I think I got it. Just to improve our conversation (if I really got it right), all other conditions like other "ANDs" (like AND myTable.FlgExample = 'T') that may appear in the where clause after the ( *= ) should go the the new "LEFT [OUTER] JOIN" (don't know if I made it clear enough to understand). Correct?